# Check In of file using REST API to Sharepoint 2013 not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am performing Check Out and Check In of File in Sharepoint using Javascript with REST API. For syntax reference, i have referred to https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest.

I get the following error which is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "The parameter parameters does not exist in method CheckIn."
    }
  }
}
```

Please find the screenshot of the REQUEST which is been posted from REST CLIENT.

[image]

Kindly note that in the Sharepoint 2013 server "as" is the Collection Site name and and "DocTest" is the Document library name where I have the file "1.txt" uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space between 
You

`CheckIn(comment='Comment', checkintype=0)`

Example on referred document

`CheckIn(comment='Comment',checkintype=0)`